# Push notification for web application From one module to other module

Tags: php, ajax, push-notification

i have integrated the notification system for web to android and Apple.
but now i have to integrate the notification system for web application part .

**For ex.
currently i am working on restaurant project.
Now When customer Order From his / her mobile application on that time i have to show his/her order in Kitchen department . for that i have to Run ajax From kitchen department module  to check that customer is ordered anything.**

but the problem is when we run ajax every single minute then it will affect the server. because most of the server are not compatible ( for handling so many ajax request. ).

so i thought can we integrate the concept as same as push notification service for android and ios.

or anything else (different concept) for this one. please suggest a new idea.

i thought many option but at last time it will reach to the solution ajax request

Comment: are you talking about a web-application or a smartphone-app? if you are talking about a web-application you should check out websockets(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Browser_compatibility). with websockets you can implement something very similar to the `push` technology you are talking about.

Comment: If you are doing it in php than http://socketo.me one of the simplest implementation of web sockets.